# Modify `\funcdef` macro to use `pgfkeys` instead of `keyval`

Tags: macros, expansion, pgfkeys, key-value

I attempted to modify the `\funcdef` macro from egreg's solution from [A macro adding or removing parenthesis automatically](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/149727/4301) to use `pgfkeys`, but am running into some difficulty (probably related to some expansion issues). The text highlighted in red details the failing conditions:

[image]

### Notes:

- The MWE seems long due to the `\funcdef` code, which is here in case one wishes to see the results with the other macro. The issues here are all related to the `\FunctionMap` macro.
- The main differences between the `\FunctionMap` macro here and the linked `\funcdef` (other than using `pgfkeys` instead of `keyval`) is that `\FunctionMap`:

  - Requires both `domain=` and `codomain=` to be specified.
  - If `variable=` is provided then `notation=` must also be provided.
  - Only use an `array` if `variable=` is provided.

### Questions:

- What changes are needed to resolve the failing conditions highlighted in red.
- What case requires the use of the

  ```
  \ifx\Notation\@empty
      \expandafter\@gobble
  \else
      \expandafter\@firstofone
  \fi
  ```

### References:

- [What do \@firstoftwo and \@secondoftwo do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21262/4301).
- The `funcdef` macro is from [A macro adding or removing parenthesis automatically](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/149727/4301).
- How to use of `pgfkeys` is explained [How to create a command with key values?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34318/4301).

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,keyval}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{xcolor}


\makeatletter%% ------ egreg's version from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/149727/4301
\newcommand{\funcdef@key}[1]{%
  \define@key{funcdef}{#1}{\@namedef{cet@#1}{##1}}%
  \expandafter\let\csname cet@#1\endcsname\@empty
}
\funcdef@key{name}
\funcdef@key{domain}
\funcdef@key{codomain}
\funcdef@key{variable}
\funcdef@key{variables}
\funcdef@key{notation}
\funcdef@key{definition}
\newcommand{\funcdef@check}[1]{%
  \expandafter\ifx\csname cet@#1\endcsname\@empty
    \@latex@error{Missing `#1'}{Provide `#1'}%
  \fi
}

\newcommand{\funcdef}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \setkeys{funcdef}{#1}%
  \ifx\cet@codomain\@empty\let\cet@codomain\cet@domain\fi
  \funcdef@check{name}%
  \funcdef@check{domain}%
  \ifx\cet@variables\@empty
    \funcdef@check{variable}%
  \fi
  \begin{array}{l@{}r@{}l@{}l}
  \cet@name\colon{} & 
  \cet@domain &
  {}\to \cet@codomain \\
  &
  \ifx\cet@variable\@empty
    (\cet@variables)
  \else
    \cet@variable
  \fi &
  {}\mapsto
  \ifx\cet@notation\@empty
    \cet@name(
      \ifx\cet@variable\@empty
        \cet@variables
      \else
        \cet@variable
      \fi
    )
  \else
    \cet@notation
  \fi
  \ifx\cet@definition\@empty
    \expandafter\@gobble
  \else
    \expandafter\@firstofone
  \fi
  {& {}\mathrel{:}=\cet@definition}
  \\
  \end{array}
  \endgroup
}
\makeatletter


%% -------------------------------- Modified pgfkeys version.
\pgfkeys{%
    %% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34318/4301
    /FunctionMap/.is family,% Define family directory
    /FunctionMap,%            Switch to this directory
    default/.style={% Defaults 
       variable={},
       %%notation={},%% No default so we get an error if variable is specified, but notation is not
    },
    name/.estore in = \Name,
    domain/.estore in = \Domain,
    codomain/.estore in = \Codomain,
    variable/.estore in = \Variable,      
    notation/.estore in = \Notation,% Error if this is not specified, but variable is
}%
\newcommand{\FunctionMap}[1]{%
    %% Requires both "domain=" and "codomain=" to be specified.
    %% if "variable=" is provided then "notation=" must also be provided.
    %% Only use an array if variable is provided
  \begingroup%
    \pgfkeys{/FunctionMap, default, #1}%
    \IfStrEq{\Variable}{}{%
          \Name\colon{} 
                  \Domain
                  {}\mathrel{\to} \Codomain
    }{%
        \begin{array}{@{}l@{}r@{}l@{}l}
            % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37791/4301
            \Name\colon{} 
              & \Domain 
              & {}\mathrel{\to} \Codomain
                \\
              & \Variable
                \ifx\Notation\@empty
                    \expandafter\@gobble
                \else
                    \expandafter\@firstofone
                \fi
              & {}\mathrel{\mapsto} \Notation
        \end{array}%
  }%
  \endgroup
}%

%% To switch to use \funcdef
%\let\FunctionMap\funcdef

\newcommand*{\Error}[1]{(\textcolor{red}{#1})}%

\begin{document}

\noindent
Simple function \Error{want to use `$\mathbf{R}$' here instead of `$R$'}:
\[
    \FunctionMap{%
        name=f,
        domain=R, %\mathbf{R},% fails
        codomain=R,% \mathbf{R},% fails
        variable=x,
        notation=f(x),
    }
\]
Simple function with declaration:
\[
\FunctionMap{%
  name=f,
  domain=R,
  codomain=R,
  variable=x,
  notation=x^2,
}
\]
Function with alternative writing \Error{Want to use `$\exp$' here instead of `$f$'}:
\[
\FunctionMap{%
  name=f, %%  \exp,% <-- fails
  domain=R,
  codomain=R,
  variable=x,
  notation=e^x
}
\]
Function with alternative writing and declaration:
\[
\FunctionMap{%
  name=g,
  variable=x,
  domain=R,
  codomain=R,
  notation={e^x:=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac xn\right)^n}
}
\]
Function with different domain and codomain
\Error{Want to use `$\operatorname{sqrt}$' and `$\sqrt{n}$' here instead of `$sqrt$'}:
\[
\FunctionMap{%
  name=sqrt, %%\operatorname{sqrt},% <-- fails
  domain=N,  %\mathbf{N},%           <-- fails
  codomain=R,%\mathbf{R},%           <-- fails
  variable=n,
  notation=sqrt{n}, %% \sqrt{n},%    <-- fails
}
\]
%Function with different domain and codomain, alternative writing
%and declaration:
%\[
%\FunctionMap{%
%  name=\operatorname{sqrt},
%  domain=\mathbf{N},
%  codomain=\mathbf{R},
%  variable=n,
%  notation=\sqrt{n},
%  definition=\exp\bigl(\frac{1}{2}\ln n\bigr)
%}
%\]
Function of two variables:
\[
\FunctionMap{%
  name=f,
  domain=A\times B,
  codomain=C,
  variable={(a,b)},
  notation=f(x),
}
\]
Function of with just domain and codomain:
\[
\FunctionMap{%
  name=f,
  domain=X,
  codomain=Y,
}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: /.estore in expands the argument so mathbf is destined to fail there. I think you just need to collect the tokens.

Comment: @percusse: Well, that certainly was easy.. Thanks. You want to post that as an answer?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was solved in the comments.