# Macro with local variables expanding over several tab-points

Tags: macros, arrays

I finally developed from [egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/149725/36281) in my previous question ( [Defining a macro with three optional arguments in the form \newmacro{a}{b}[c]{d}[e][f] and \newmacro{a}{b}[c]{d}*[f]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/149705/36281) )
While my original answer was about making a shorter code, I ended up with a ~190 lines package.  For the curious you can check it [here in github](https://github.com/chlewey/chlewtex/blob/master/tex/latex/chlewtex/chlewfunc.sty), and it is also documented [here](http://claro.chlewey.net/samples/chlewfunc.pdf).

The macro works fine, except for a display mode I would like to achieve: I want
the macro to work inside tabular environments such as `array` or `align`:
that would allow to typeset several function definitions preserving some alignment.

However I found a problem.

Let's took a look of the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\tempi{0}
\def\tempii{1}
\newcommand\mymacro[1]{
  \let\tempiii\tempi
  \def\tempi{#1\tempiii}
  \def\tempii{#1}
  \mymacroi
}
\newcommand\mymacroi{\tempi & \tempii}
\begin{document}
\[
  \begin{array}{cccc}
    a & \mymacro{1} & b \\
    \mymacro{2} & \mymacro{3}
  \end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

It gets this result: [image: a 10 1 b // 20 1 30 1]

Changing the definition of `\mymacroi`

```
\newcommand\mymacroi{\tempi , \tempii}
```

The new result is: [image: 1 10,1 b // 20,2 30,3]

In the first code, the changes in `\tempii` are not preserved after the tab character `&`.  The second one shows the modification of `\tempii` (but does not align).

Using `\begingroup` in `\mymacro`:

```
\newcommand\mymacro[1]{
  \begingroup
  \let\tempiii\tempi
  \def\tempi{#1\tempiii}
  \def\tempii{#1}
  \mymacroi
  \endgroup
}
```

And, with the original `\mymacroi` (the one with `&`) I get an error.

So the problem is indeed trying to use `&` from the macro, while preserving
changes local to my macro, while expanding these changes over several cells.

---

(In this MWE there is a circular reference which does not exist in my original macro.)

---

**Update:**
My original example was too simple to show some desired result, and given that my macro should work both inside tabular environment and non-tabular environments, I will mimic that in this MWE by redefining `\mymacroi`.  I copy only the document environment.

```
\begin{document}
\[
  \begin{array}{cccccc}
    a & \mymacro{7} & b & \tempi & \tempii \\
    \mymacro{2} & \mymacro{3} & \tempi & \tempii 
  \end{array}
\]
\renewcommand\mymacroi{%
  \edef\tmp{\tempi,\tempii}%
  \tmp
}
\par Test 1 \(\mymacro{5};\tempi,\tempii\)
\par Test 2 \(\mymacro{4};\tempi,\tempii\)
\end{document}
```

The expected result is:
[image: array-check]
and
[image: non-array-check]

Answer (score 5):

Each of the cells within the table forms a group. So, your use of

```
\mymacro{2}
```

expands to

```
\let\tempiii\tempi
\def\tempi{2\tempiii}
\def\tempii{2}
\mymacroi
```

which defines `\tempi` as `2\tempiii` (which is equivalent to `2\tempi`) and `\tempii` as `2`. Then you call `\mymacroi` which expands to

```
\tempi & \tempii
```

Both `\tempi` and `\tempii` are defined, but the updated definition was done inside the (first) group/cell. As such, the second cell containing `\tempii` would revert back to the original definition (as done in the preamble as `\def\tempii{1}`). This happens with every use of `\mymacro`, and it seems like you wish to have your local re-definitions to span across these cells. To do that, use a `g`lobal re-`def`inition (or possibly an e`x`panded global re-`def`inition):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\tempi{0}
\newcommand\tempii{1}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\storetemps}{%
  \global\let\store@tempi\tempi%
  \global\let\store@tempii\tempii}
\newcommand{\restoretemps}{%
  \global\let\tempi\store@tempi%
  \global\let\tempii\store@tempii}
\newcommand\mymacro[1]{
  \storetemps%
  \xdef\tempi{#1\tempi}%
  \xdef\tempii{#1}%
  \mymacroi%
}
\newcommand\mymacroi{%
  \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\@currenvir}{array}=0
    \let\select@type\@firstoftwo%
  \else
    \let\select@type\@secondoftwo%
  \fi
  \select@type{\tempi & \tempii}{\tempi, \tempii}%
  \restoretemps%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
$
  \begin{array}{cccccc}
    a & \mymacro{7} & b & \tempi & \tempii \\
    \mymacro{2} & \mymacro{3} & \tempi & \tempii 
  \end{array}
$

Test 1 \(\mymacro{5};\tempi,\tempii\) \par
Test 2 \(\mymacro{4};\tempi,\tempii\)
\end{document}
```

The above version of `\mymacroi` conditions on whether you're in an `array` environment or not, allowing you to use it as-is inside one or not.

Comment: This solves part of the problem: having `\tempii` preserved inside `\mymacro` over the cells.  But then `\tempii` is also redefine outside `\mymacro` which is not desired.  This example was probably too simple to show that part of the intended effect.

Comment: @CarlosEugenioThompsonPinzón: Yes, it doesn't make sense, since `\tempii` is used nowhere else. However, you could use an alternative macro name, or restore it using another `\gdef` after using it. But I would need more information to clearly help you.

Comment: I updated the question to add a more complicated example showing desired effect.  See also comment to David's answer.

Comment: @CarlosEugenioThompsonPinzón: I've updated my answer. Let me know if it works for you now.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

You appear to want to expand the macros in the current group but evaluate them in a different group, so separate expansion and typesetting with `\edef` (or if there are any user supplied LaTeX input, `\protected@edef`). Also you had several `%` missing from ends of lines.

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\tempi{0}
\def\tempii{1}
\newcommand\mymacro[1]{%
  \let\tempiii\tempi
  \def\tempi{#1\tempiii}%
  \def\tempii{#1}%
  \mymacroi
}
\newcommand\mymacroi{%
\edef\tmp{\tempi&\tempii}%
\tmp}

\begin{document}
\[
  \begin{array}{cccc}
    a & \mymacro{1} & b \\
    \mymacro{2} & \mymacro{3}
  \end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: My current actual macro is working with `\begingroup`, `\endgroup`, as there are too many variables that might be touched and need to be reseted for the next call.  I've upvoted your answer and updated (and complicated) the request.

Comment: @CarlosEugenioThompsonPinzón I don't see the updated question changes anything, this produces the desired result. You can't use grouping as you want the results to be visible in a different group. `& &` is a group the same as `{ }` as far as macro expansion is concerned. So I wouldn't change this answer given the updated question.